# I'm working through the donut tutorial and am having an issue when selecting and grabbing a single vertex in Proportional Editing mode

Tags: modeling, vertices

When I select just 1 vertex and Grab with Proportional Editing on, the mesh breaks after I move the vertex. I don't see this happening in the tutorial. Seems like a bug?
Am I missing something?
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may find that the circle of influence is much too large when you start using proportional edit and in fact it can be large enough to disappear offscreen. While you're grabbing the vertex, scroll the mouse wheel down and you'll see the circle of influence reduce to a reasonable size and the vertex movement should then be more controllable. In any case that image shows that you have two vertices selected, not one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There's actually just 1 vertex selected. As far as I can see anyway. Does Blender have a heads up display like Maya that shows info like that? Selected faces, vertices etc? I think the issue I was having is a bug. My circle of influence was at .040. A reasonable size. But if I had Grab selected and I changed the size to something smaller the points moved back to their proper location.?

Comment: If it was a bug, it's not one I've heard about! What Blender version are you using? The info (including Blender's version)  should all be in the bottom status bar on the right-hand side. For instance, if you have the default cube in edit mode with one vertex selected, the status line will start: "Cube | Verts 1/8 | Edges 0/12 ..." etc. (1 vertex selected of 8 in the object).

Comment: I'm using Blender version 3.2.2. But I had to go to the Blender menu in the top left corner to find that. I do see 3.2.2 in the bottom right corner of the GUI but no other info.

Comment: Sounds as if you have all the options turned off under Edit > Preferences > Interface > Status Bar in that case. They're all checked here and were by default when Blender was installed as far as I can remember, You can also right-click on the status bar and enable them from the popup menu there.

Comment: Not sure how that got turned off. Got the display back now though. Cheers!